# Problem with gcc 4.6 installation on ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install gcc 4.6 (mainly for having C++0x better supported) in my ubuntu 9.10 (via virtualbox). I referred to [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886259/gcc-4-5-installation-problem-under-ubuntu), but I am getting a different error.

I am referring [this link for the installation](http://buildall.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/installing-gcc-4-6-in-the-ubuntu-10-10/). Now, I have done till the `./gcc-xx/configure ...` step. Though it was giving some flex package related error. Mostly due to that `make` is also failing with below errors:

> build/gengtype.o: In function
>   `adjust_field_rtx_def':
>   /home/milind/ubuntu_shared/GCC/build/gcc/../../gcc-4.6-20110610/gcc/gengtype.c:978:
>   undefined reference to`lexer_line'
>   /home/milind/ubuntu_shared/GCC/build/gcc/../../gcc-4.6-20110610/gcc/gengtype.c:1032:
>   undefined reference to `lexer_line'
>   /home/milind/ubuntu_shared/GCC/build/gcc/../../gcc-4.6-20110610/gcc/gengtype.c:1042:
>   undefined reference to`lexer_line' ...............

Now this is giving me a hard time figuring it out because I have already `flex/bison` latest versions installed. I searched over internet for 2 days almost but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated. Also note that, I already have `gcc 4.4` installed in `/usr/bin/gcc` and I have unzipped the `gcc 4.6` tar in my home directory local folder.

[Note: I am also ok with installing `ubuntu 11.10` too  (which has gcc 4.6) as last resort. But I don't know if its `.iso` image is available.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this fixed. I followed following procedure:
[Note: **run all the commands** with `sudo`, if you are not login as root. e.g. `sudo ls -ltr; sudo make install;`

1. As mentioned in the link in my
   question, download the `gcc4.6...tar`
   file in a temporary place
2. Now find the place where current
   `gcc` is stored. e.g. My earlier
   `gcc4.4` was stored in
   `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu`. Which
   has a folder called `4.4`, `4.4.1`
3. Create a folder named `4.6` (or
   `4.6.1/2/3` etc.) and put that
   `.tar` file inside it. Untar the
   file as shown in link.
4. Follow all the procedure as per the
   link. Use `nohup <command> &` to
   track the logs. i.e. `nohup make
   clean all &` followed by `tail -f
   nohup.out`
5. If some error comes, it means some
   package is missing. Mostly those
   package will be present in your
   current `gcc` version. You can
   install them there itself. For
   example, in my case `zlib` was
   missing. I ran `sudo apt-get install
   zlib1g-dev libssl-dev` and it worked
   fine. Otherwise download from internet and install it.
6. Once your `gcc` is installed, you
   can simply check it using `type
   gcc-4.6`. In my case it showed that
   it's stored as
   `/usr/local/bin/g++-4.6`.
7. Either you can use the same path to
   compile or you can put an `alias` in
   your `bash/tcsh/ksh`. e.g.
   `/usr/local/bin/g++-4.6 -std=c++0x
   -Wall test.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

FWIW Debian testing and unstable have gcc-4.6 as a standard package. So you can simply install that distro inside of virtualbox or, as I've done on my Ubuntu 11.04 server at home, via kvm. In the past, I also used to use `dchroot` build environments.

There may also be prepackaged gcc-4.6 binaries at launchpad.

Comment: +1, thanks. However, there is no way to overcome those flex or bison errors ? Is there anything related to path which can fix them. i.e. I should be `./configure`ing gcc from certain path or something like that ?

Comment: There usually is. I sometimes builds local Ubuntu packages from the Debian package sources. But this is a biggy -- you may need a new libc6 and all that -- so why not just virtualize the distro into an appliance?