# IS there any way to get back(temporarily) old G++3.2 version with out modifying the new version?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

earlier iam having G++ 3.2 version ..latest i installed GCC 4.5.2
and i have EDG vold version EDG 3.10

the problem is now when i try to run the C++ files with EDG (noramally to run EDG ,G++ is needed as a flag) now latest G++ is not supporting to run EDG3.10

so ineed temporarily to run old G++3.2 version....

IS there any way to get back(temporarily) old G++3.2 version with out modifying the new version?

please tell me the way to run old G++3.2 Temporarily..with out effecting new G++ 4.5.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which version of GCC that you wish, just compile it from source code. [Here](http://gcc.cybermirror.org/releases/) you got GCC 2.95.1 to 4.5.2 available for download.

After downloading, execute :

```
./configure
make
make install
```

to compile it and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I tried to install GCC-4.6. I have documented my findings [in answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372600/problem-with-gcc-4-6-installation-on-ubuntu). You can download the `tar` for gcc3.x from the website and follow the same procedure.